# Developing intersection widget using script ArcPy and geoprocessing service?

Tags: arcpy, intersection, geoprocessing-service

Is it possible to develop an intersection widget with geoprocessing service using ArcPy script?

I try to do that with ModelBuilder but after publishing, in geoprocessing service i don't find my inputs among the parameters.